# Scrapy Spider not writing to Postgres in the correct format

Tags: scrapy

I'm scraping the Science of Us website for articles related to mental health and trying to dump it to a postgres database I'm running locally. The scrapy output is stored in a dictionary that looks like `articles = {'title': [], 'teaser': [], 'link': [], 'date': [], 'author': [], 'source': []}`

On running my code, it dumps the entire list of values for each key into the column with name == key. Instead, I would like each article to be one row in the database e.g. Article 1 would have its own row with its title, teaser, link, date, author and source in each of the columns.

Here is the relevant code:
1) `spider.py`

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy import Request
from mhnewsbot_app.items import SOUItem
import string

mh_search_terms = ["DEPRESS", "MENTAL HEALTH", "EMOTIONAL HEALTH", "MENTAL DISORDER", "DIGITAL MEDICINE", "ANXI", "PSYCH", "THERAPY", "THERAPIST"]
tbl = string.maketrans('-', ' ') #To protect against cases where the article has hyphens or other special characters

articles = {'title': [], 'teaser': [], 'link': [], 'date': [], 'author': [], 'source': []}

def url_lister():
  url_list = []
  article_count = 0
  while article_count < 150:                                            
    url = 'http://nymag.com/scienceofus/?start=%s' %article_count
    url_list.append(url)
    article_count += 50
  return url_list

class SOUSpider(Spider):
  name = 'scienceofus'
  start_urls = url_lister()

def parse(self, response):
    for article in response.xpath('//ul[@class="newsfeed-article-list"]'):
        title = article.xpath('.//li[contains(@class, "newsfeed-article")]/div[@class="headline-wrapper"]/a[@class="headline-link"]/h3[@class="headline"]').extract()
        for i in title:
            for search_term in mh_search_terms:
                if search_term in i.upper().strip():
                    articles['title'].append(article.xpath('.//li[contains(@class, "newsfeed-article")]/div[@class="headline-wrapper"]/a[@class="headline-link"]/h3[@class="headline"]/text()').extract()[title.index(i)])
                    articles['teaser'].append(article.xpath('.//li[contains(@class, "newsfeed-article")]/p[@class = "teaser"]/text()').extract()[title.index(i)])
                    articles['link'].append(article.xpath('.//li[contains(@class, "newsfeed-article")]/a[@class = "read-more"]/@href').extract()[title.index(i)])
                    articles['date'].append(article.xpath('.//li[contains(@class, "newsfeed-article")]/div[@class="headline-wrapper"]/div[@class="headline-above"]/time/text()').extract()[title.index(i)])
                    articles['author'].append(article.xpath('.//li[contains(@class, "newsfeed-article")]/span[@class="by-authors"]/span/span[@class="author"]/text()').extract()[title.index(i)])
                    articles['source'].append('Science Of Us')
    return articles
```

2) `pipelines.py`

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from models import Articles, db_connect, create_articles_table

class ArticlesPipeline(object):
  def __init__(self):
      engine = db_connect()
      create_articles_table(engine)
      self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

def process_item(self, item, spider):
  session = self.Session()
    article = Articles(**item)

    try:
        session.add(article)
        session.commit()
    except :
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()

    return item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are outputting 1 item, with multiple values on their fields, better output one item per value, because that's how your database seems to accept it:

```
 def parse(self, response):
for article in response.xpath('//ul[@class="newsfeed-article-list"]'):
    title = article.xpath('.//li[contains(@class, "newsfeed-article")]/div[@class="headline-wrapper"]/a[@class="headline-link"]/h3[@class="headline"]').extract()
    for i in title:
        for search_term in mh_search_terms:
            if search_term in i.upper().strip():
                article_item = {}
                article_item['title'] = article.xpath('.//li[contains(@class, "newsfeed-article")]/div[@class="headline-wrapper"]/a[@class="headline-link"]/h3[@class="headline"]/text()').extract()[title.index(i)]
                article_item['teaser'] = article.xpath('.//li[contains(@class, "newsfeed-article")]/p[@class = "teaser"]/text()').extract()[title.index(i)]
                article_item['link'] = article.xpath('.//li[contains(@class, "newsfeed-article")]/a[@class = "read-more"]/@href').extract()[title.index(i)]
                article_item['date'] = article.xpath('.//li[contains(@class, "newsfeed-article")]/div[@class="headline-wrapper"]/div[@class="headline-above"]/time/text()').extract()[title.index(i)]
                article_item['author'] = article.xpath('.//li[contains(@class, "newsfeed-article")]/span[@class="by-authors"]/span/span[@class="author"]/text()').extract()[title.index(i)]
                article_item['source'] = 'Science Of Us'
                yield article_item
```